# Unwanted loop in javascript functions

Tags: javascript, function, loops, video

I'm placing a video as a full background of a Website in the HTML with ID #background. when this short video ends I will apply this javascript code I made to replace (#background) video with another video that will loop. Also when this first video (#background) ends a paragraph and a heading will be added to the HTML.

Everything works but there is an unwanted loop. The second video (videohome.mp4)loops -as expected- but the paragraph and the heading duplicates in the screen over an over as the video loops. I have removed the *videoPlayer.play=loop;* from code and it does not affect the unwanted loop.
This is original HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row viewport">
            <div class="col-lg-6 align-middle animated fadeIn" id="animationtxt">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
document.getElementById("background").onended = function() {myFunction();run()};


function myFunction() {
        var h = document.createElement("H1");
        var t = document.createTextNode("Hello World");
        h.appendChild(t);
        document.getElementById("animationtxt").appendChild(h);

        var para = document.createElement("p");
        var txt = document.createTextNode("This is a paragraph.");
        para.setAttribute("class","custom-epost-txt");
        para.appendChild(txt);
        document.getElementById("animationtxt").appendChild(para);
        return;
}
videoPlayer = document.getElementById("background");
function run(){
        var nextVideo = "videos/videohome.mp4";
        videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;

        videoPlayer.play=autoplay;
        videoPlayer.play=loop;
    }
```

Comment: You need to clear `#animationtxt` before appending new content.

Comment: I'm adding the HMTL in question. There is no content in the div. Maybe you mean something else? I'm beginer in Javascript. Thank you

Comment: `document.getElementById("animationtxt").appendChild(para);` adds the content to `#animationtxt`. When the function will be run the second time, that line adds more content, etc. `appendChild` adds the content to the end of the target, it doesn't remove the exisiting content from the target.

Comment: Yes, document.getElementById("animationtxt").appendChild(para); and document.getElementById("animationtxt").appendChild(h); are both added when functions runs. In the background second video plays with a loop. I just do not want the (H) and (P) to repeat over and over they both should stay as video plays behind in a loop. I should clear the #animationtxt right?. How to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Setting its `innerHTML` to empty string is maybe the simplest way.

Comment: I have found this way to accomplish what you say, just don[t know where to place it? `var myNode = document.getElementById("animationtxt");
myNode.innerHTML = '';`